# How to receive LocalBroadcast in android service

Tags: java, android, android-service

I am trying to make an app in which I have a receiver which sends out a broadcast:

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    try {
        System.out.println("Receiver start");
        String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);

        if(state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            Intent callIntent = new Intent("INCOMING_CALL");
            callIntent.putExtra("number", incomingNumber);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
        if ((state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK))){
            //Toast.makeText(context,"Call Received State",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            //Toast.makeText(context,"Call Idle State",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

I also have a service running and I want to capture the broadcast in that service, I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
public class NotifierService extends Service
{
...//something goes here
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(lbReceiver, new IntentFilter("INCOMING_CALL"));
        return START_STICKY;
    }
    private BroadcastReceiver lbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if(action.equals("INCOMING_CALL"))
            {
//do something
            }
        }
    };
```

Can someone please tell me the correct way to receive a broadcast in a service, if it is not possible to receive a broadcast then what else can i use ?

[UPDATE]
This is how my service is declared in the manifest

```
    <service
        android:name=".NotifierService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        >
    </service>
```

Comment: Do you have an `android:process` attribute on your `<service>` element in the manifest?

Comment: @CommonsWare no it does not, i've updated my question

Comment: OK, are you sure that your service is running?

Comment: yes it is running for sure, ive seen it in the deugger

Comment: I recommend making a constant for `"INCOMING_CALL"` and using it everywhere, to avoid typos. Beyond that, if the `PhoneStateReceiver` also does not have `android:process` on the `<receiver>` element in the manifest, then both sides of the local broadcast are in the same process, so this should work. Note that a background service can only run for ~1 minute on Android 8.0+, so `NotifierService` should be a foreground service (which also means you would not be relying on the debugger to know if it is running).